# Getting specific data in node by other data in same node

Tags: c#, xml

I got XML like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Some comment-->
<Databook>
  <Note>
    <Name>Camera2 made a snapshoot #243</Name>
    <Value>Camera2_snapshoot-2013-09-06_21-47-35.png</Value>
  </Note>
  <Note>
    <Name>Camera1 made a snapshoot #244</Name>
    <Value>Camera1_snapshoot-2013-09-06_21-47-39.png</Value>
  </Note>
</Databook>
```

And i want to get string beetwen [Value]..[/Value] of specific node, knowing only it's string of [Name]..[/Name].

This what i did so far:

```
string xmlfile = string.Format("XML/Diary/" + day);
XDocument dailyXML = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);

XElement Contact = (from xml2 in dailyXML.Descendants("Note")
                    where xml2.Element("Name").Value == item
                    select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, if you just want the value of `Value` where the `Name` equals `item`

Try:

```
string result = (from xml2 in dailyXML.Descendants("Note")
                           where xml2.Element("Name").Value == item
                           select xml2.Element("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
string result = dailyXML.Descendants("Note")
                        .Where(n => n.Element("Name").Value == item)
                        .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Element("Value").Value);
```